# How to change a list to a twodarray or listOflist like shown below using groovy?

Tags: list, groovy

Here the Object is like,

**Input**

```
def mylist = ['a','b',['c1','c2','c3'],'d',['e1','e2','e3']]
```

How to get it this like a twod array as shown below,

**Expected Output**

```
[['a','b','c1','d','e1'],
['a','b','c2','d','e2'],
['a','b','c3','d','e3']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing other details, the solution to satisfy the output would be:

```
def mylist = ['a','b',['c1','c2','c3'],'d',['e1','e2','e3']]
int max = mylist.collect{ String == it.getClass() ? 1 : it.size() }.max()

def result = (0..<max).collect{ ix ->
  mylist.collect{ String == it.getClass() ? it : it[ ix ] }
}

assert result == [['a','b','c1','d','e1'], 
                  ['a','b','c2','d','e2'], 
                  ['a','b','c3','d','e3']]
```